# Use jmeter to test multiple Websites

Tags: jmeter

How to test 100 different websites (from DMOZ) using jmeter?

I think it can be done by integrating jmeter with a script. Basically the script is to tell jmeter to read the URLs from a text or csv file and changing the http request sampler to the URLs from the file to run the test and then save the test result to a file.

Any idea?

Comment: Any news on that ? Was my answer OK ? if yes you should accept it so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly implement this as per the following points:

**1.** Prepare your test-urls in csv-file, e.g. in the following format:

> ```
> url1
> url2
> ...
> urlN
> ```

**2.** Use schema for your script as below:

```
Thread Group
    . . .
    While Controller
    Condition: ${__javaScript("${testURL}"!="<EOF>",)} // read csv-file until the EOF 
        CSV Data Set Config
        Filename: [path to your csv-file with test-urls]
        Variable Names: testURL
        Recycle on EOF? False
        Stop thread on EOF? True
        Sharing mode: Current thread group
            HTTP Request // your http call
            Server Name or IP: ${testURL} // use variable with extracted URL
        . . .
```

**3.** To retain test-results you can use e.g. [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) or configure [Sample Result Save Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Result_Save_Configuration) for any of the [jmeter's out-of-the-box listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners).

Comment: thank for your help but does not seem to be working for me. or do I write a code like you have above or use the GUI?

Comment: Any errors in console output or in jmeter.log? Check also path to your csv-file in CSV Data Set Config (either absolute or relative (but in this case csv should be placed in the same dir as your test-plan)).

Comment: As well ensure that the test-URLs don't contain "http://" prefix (as per [HTTP Request params](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_parms) -> Server). Works fine [as for me](http://cl.ly/0W1p2T1c0z1J).

Comment: thank you for the answer. it was great. now do you know how to export the test result which I save in csv file to a mysql database?